# Java: how to get youtube access/refresh token for app?

Tags: java, youtube, google-api

I have google app with credentials:
app-name, api-key, client-id, client-email, client-secret ...

Is it possible to get access to youtube api without user autorization.
For example with user auth I can get refresh tokern and get access token like this:

```
 TokenResponse response = new RefreshTokenRequest( GOOGLE_HTTP_TRANSPORT, GOOGLE_JSON_FACTORY, new GenericUrl( "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token" ), channelYoutubeAccess.getRefreshToken() ).setClientAuthentication( new ClientParametersAuthentication( getGoogleClientId(), getGoogleClientSecret() ) ).execute();
    if( response != null ) {
      accessToken = response.getAccessToken();
    }
```

Could you help me. Thank you.

Comment: The user will have to authenticate you the first time after that you should be able to use your refresh token to get another access token.

Comment: I need get access token without user auth. I have only app credentials...

Comment: I don't think you understand the point of Open Authentication.   You cant access someone's data unless they authenticate you.    all the credentials do is identify your application to Google and the user whos data you wish to access.   There for you cant get an access token with out a user authenticating you first.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=QK8mJJJvaes&_h=4&

```
final YouTube.Videos.List listRq = youtube.videos().list("id, status").setId(id).setKey(CLIENT_KEY);
        VideoListResponse searchResponse = listRq.execute();
```